# Laravel server without php artisan serve command

Tags: php, laravel, vps, digital-ocean

I am using Laravel for RestApi and use Angularjs for front-end. I successfully build application in my system and deploy project to DigitalOcean Ubuntu VPS. When I serve a Laravel development server using php artisan serve command it start `http://localhost:8000` server the api works fine if I turn off putty(use as DigitalOcean client) the Api not working. This is use for development environment but now project running on VPS and RestAPI not working. Please suggest me that how I use Laravel RestAPI in VPS without php artisan serve command.

Comment: have you change URL in app/config/app.php

Comment: Thank you. I used your suggestion but not woking.

Comment: in digitalocean, vritual host is api.foodbucket.com and I have added this in app.php

Comment: Dude you need to set up virtual host as part of your Nginx or apache servers and let it point to the location where your app/public is located

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-lts-vps) article with the title "How To Install Laravel with Nginx on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VPS". That article should help you getting REST API working without PHP artisan `serve`.

Basically, `php artisan serve` is used to run PHP's built-in web server. When you are already using nginx, you don't need to run PHP's built-in web server. So, you won't need to run `php artisan serve`.

Comment: I've clicked the article and it contains a lengthy installation guide. So I've helped by just including the title as explanation, hope that that is enough.

Comment: I have already installed nginx and i have use it for laravel. Everything is work good but API not work without **php artisan serve**.